# TYPO3 mm-Query giving me no output and no error

Tags: php, sql, database, typo3, relation

I've tried to output some data from my two linked tables and had a look at all examples I could find, but I'm still not getting any results. (Note: I've tried exec_SELECTquery on either table and it worked like a charm)

So here's my code

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debugOutput = true;

$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query(
  'tx_pagecat_category.title',  // $select_fields
  'tx_pagecat_category',    // $local_table
  'pages_tx_pagecat_category_mm',   // $mm_table
  'pages',  // $foreign_table
  '',   //$where_clause
  '',   // $groupBy
  '',   // $orderBy
  ''    // $limit
);

while( $row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    $c= $row['tx_pagecat_category.title'].chr(10);
}

return $this->pi_wrapInBaseClass($c);
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong, even the Debug-Output is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->store_lastBuiltQuery = 1;

// query here

echo $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debug_lastBuiltQuery;
```

That will give you the sql sent to the db. You can then run that query manually to check what's wrong.